# Advice on Facebook Registration Plugin

Tags: facebook, registration

Ok so I am wanting to add the ability for users to use their facebook accounts to register to a site. I have gone through the dev files and various tutorials online. The issue is that no matter what method I follow I have yet been able to get it to work.

I have tried using source from here as well:
http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-facebook-registration-plugin-as-your-registration-system/15/

Is there some dependency that I need for the site, some other system for facebook to load right?

Here is the test version of the site: http://ohmsgaming.com/Misc/nstdt/v2/

Comment: I am still lost on this, I have managed to make the register part to sort of load, but it only is working in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page show an error like "'redirect_uri' should be an absolute url."

Use absolute Uri in redirect Url field of request query to fix the issue.

You can use Open Authentication technique to set up authentication system in your site. And once the user is authenticated you will get the publicly shared information of the user. This information can be registered in website at first login.

I successfully implemented the same in http://www.nowrunning.com using brickred's social auth code.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Well that is interesting I am not seeing that error, via firebug or anything. I will look into the brickreds code though it looks like it isnt in php.

Comment: I am confused on how I would use that source you linked to, care to explain more about it?

Comment: @Tempus35 i'm not good in php, I did it in asp.net, I think you can use the java version. ok but i ll explain the steps I have done..

First the app will request an access token to facebook, and once the token receives it will request for user profile.

When the profile JSON received we will insert the user profile in our website if the profile isn't already available, if it already available just updates the changes.